# RIA Services + Entities - Date moving 24 hours earlier in client

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, silverlight

I am currently working on a silverlight project with RIA Services and have seem to come across a bug(or wrote a new one).

In a simple query I am retrieving a entity model from the server. In the server side service class a DateTime is correct(to what's in the db) but on the client it seems to go back 24 hours and maybe 10 hours...

I have not idea why, it is very strange.

6/04/2009 12:00:00 AM (Database) turns into 5/04/2009 2:00:00 PM and also displays as 5/4/2009 12:00:00 AM.

See attached.....

Is this a bug or a lack of my understanding DateTime?

[alt text http://www.madhousedesigns.com.au/Custom/Images/CrazyDateTimes.png](http://www.madhousedesigns.com.au/Custom/Images/CrazyDateTimes.png)

Comment: This sounds like a timezone issue.  What is the value stored in the database, and what timezone is it on the database server, webserver, and client?

Comment: Also, in that screenshot, it looks like you're looking at the 'date' property.  That will *always* return you the DateTime with the time component changed to 12:00:00AM (midnight), since .NET does not have a 'Date' type.

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the date, convert the DateTime kind to UTC.  This should resolve your issue.